# How to send private message in Microsoft Teams using bot on behalf of user in Teams?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We can send private messages from a Microsoft Bot to a Teams user. It appears as a chat between bot and a user.

But I need a functionality where a bot can send message on behalf of user in Teams and it would exactly appears as a 1:1 chat of two users in Teams, not as a chat between bot and a user.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending messages in Teams with a bot on behalf of a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58602926/sending-messages-in-teams-with-a-bot-on-behalf-of-a-user)

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT, Nope it doesn't. The question link that you have added here talks about posting message in channels of Teams. But I need to send private message to user.

Comment: The answer is the same though. 1. Can't do it directly with the Bot Framework. Only works with [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT  The problem is Graph API is not available to send private messages. Currently they are only available for posting messages in Channels. So I'm looking to achieve through Bot Framework if doable.

Comment: Sorry, meant [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). Regardless, this is definitely not doable directly through the Bot Framework. If you can get Graph API to support it, you have to integrate that code into your bot.

Comment: @jayanta Currently we do not have any Graph APIs to send a private message to a user. We are working on it but we do not have an ETA to share.